# MySQL Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema cuando intento crear una tabla con dos "foreign key", tengo una tabla usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario (
  id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  contrasena varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  rol varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

y otra tabla llamada chat, que la que tiene las dos "foreign keys":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
  id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombreChat varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  idUsuario int(4) NOT NULL,
  emailUsuario varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (emailUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Cuando intento ejecutarlo MySQl me da este error:

> *Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"*

He probado esta otra sintaxis también:

```
ALTER TABLE chat
  ADD CONSTRAINT chat_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT chat_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (emailUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (email) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en inglés. **El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.** por lo tanto te sugiero modificar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero:

Necesitas completar la sentencia sobre llaves foráneas de esta manera:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_chat_users FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario(id)
```

Segundo debes tener solamente una llave foránea vinculada a una llave primaria entre dos tablas, quiero decir que conectar usuarios con chat por la llave primaria de usuarios, tienes que declarar una llave foránea en chat para usuarios.

Cree dos tablas con las consideraciones que menciono

Creo que tu ejemplo debería ser del modo siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario (
  id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  contrasena varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  rol varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
  id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombreChat varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  idUsuario int(4) NOT NULL,
  emailUsuario varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_chat_usuario (idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (id)
  -- FOREIGN KEY (emailUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (email) creo que esta línea no es necesaria
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: No es malo, pero normalmente hay dos opciones, que son esperar a que se traduzca la pregunta o comentarle el sitio en inglés donde puede preguntarlo.

Comment: Podrías haber todamo el camino largo en vez de la salida facil y no tener un voto negativo de la siguiente forma: primero contestas en castellano, segundo traduces la pregunta a castellano, tercero, creas la pregunta en el sitio en inglés con su autorespuesta en inglés y finalmente le comentas que en caso de no entender lo publicaste en el sitio en inglés con su respectivo link, pudiendo obtener puntos acá y puntos en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: Alfredo me ha contestado en inglés porque he formulado la pregunta en ese idioma, es absurdo votar a alguien negativamente por contestarme en el mismo idioma, si te molesta que haga la pregunta en español votame negativamente a mi, pero no a él que me ha ayudado, de todas maneras me parece absurdo ese voto negativo, un saludo.

Comment: @DavidZam ya levanté el reporte de la pregunta como "debería ser cerrada" por el motivo de que "no pertenece a este sitio" ya que "la pregunta está en unglés, este es un sitio en español", el proceso de moderación normal es cerrala y queda en espera parra su eliminación a menos que algúyn alma caritativa la traduzca a castellano. En caso de ser eliminada ambos pierden la reputación que hayan ganado con ella o recupean la que hayan perdido. Alfredo lleva más tiempo y te puede explicar todo eso a detalle.

Comment: @DavidZam el cerrar una pregunta es una ayuda para vos ya que evita en primer lugar que caigan los votos negativos tan comunes en este sitio a las preguntas hechas en inglés, tal vez por ser fin de semana no hayan llovido aún

Comment: JorgeSys ya he puesto mi respuesta completa en español

Comment: @AlfredoPaz muchas gracias Alfredo.

Comment: Jorgesys, gracias a ti siempre es bueno recibir apoyo